# ¿Cómo puedo hacer este If anidado? C++

Tags: c++, condiciones

Trato de hacer un `if` anidado, mediante el cual pueda elegir una opción del menú, pero, al intentar seleccionar una opción, se selecciona la opción deseada, pero además salen las otras opciones.

Esto he tratado de solucionarlo con el "`switch`", pero no resulta como esperaría, trate de eliminar las opciones no seleccionadas con más parámetros del "`if`", pero o no me resulta la operación deseada, o no me deja seleccionar una opción.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    
    float costop, cantidadp, precio, descuento, mem;
    
    printf("Ingrese el costo del producto: \n $");
    scanf("%f", &costop);
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de los productos: \n");
    scanf("%f", &cantidadp);
    precio=(costop*cantidadp);
    printf("1. A(Pulse 1) \n");
    printf("2. B(Pulse 2) \n");
    printf("3. C (Pulse 3) \n");
    printf("4. D(Pulse 4) \n");
    scanf("%f", &mem);
    if(mem<0&&mem>4){
        printf("Opción invalida");
    }
    else{
        if(mem>0&&mem<2)
            printf(" no se hará descuento \n");
        precio=(costop*cantidadp);
        printf("El precio total es: \n $");
        printf("%f",&precio);
    }
    if(mem>1&&mem<3)
    {
        printf("se hará un 15 por ciento de descuento");
        descuento= precio*(precio*0.15);
        printf("El precio total es: \n $");
        printf("%f",&descuento);
        if(mem>2&&mem<4)
            printf("se hará un 20 por ciento de descuento");
        descuento= precio*(precio*0.2);
        printf("El precio total es: \n $");
        printf("%f",&descuento);
    }
    else (mem=4);
    printf(" se hará un 25 por ciento de descuento");
    descuento= precio*(precio*0.25);
    printf("El precio total es: \n $");
    printf("%f",&descuento);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas. Es mejor si colocas el código escrito en vez de una imagen. Te recomiendo que veas la sección de [ask] y tambien hagas el [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Inicialmente la condición para tu opción invalida esta mal evaluada, debido a que las dos condiciones son con un `and` intermedio y no existe un número menor que 0 y mayor que 4 a la vez. Solo es necesario cambiar por un `or`

```
if( mem < 1 || mem > 4 ){
    printf("Opción invalida");
}
```

Después de esto estoy algo confundido con tus condicionales, ya que logro entender que estas, finalmente, comparando números con `mem`, para que sea más sencillo el entendimiento podrías cambiar las condiciones por comparaciones concretas.

```cpp
if (mem < 1 || mem > 4) {...}
else if (mem == 1) {...}
else if (mem == 2) {...}
else if (mem == 3) {...}
else {...}
```

Por ultimo, en tus impresiones `printf("%f",&precio);` no es correcto que la variable que imprimes, en seguida del formato, tenga el símbolo de referencia `&`, solo sería `printf("%f",precio);`